# Prompt the user to fill the linked list

Tags: c++, list

I'm trying to fill the already created linked list by traversing the linked list and then fill each node data with the user input but for some reason after 1040 times it stops asking further values. However let's say I have link list of size 1000 it will work just fine but for more than size of 1040 It doesn't prompt the user. I'm not entering value each time I generated random 1100 elements which I'm copying to the console.

```
inline void myArray<T>::init() {
 Node<T>* temp = head;
T input;
    while(temp!=NULL) {
    cin >> input;
    temp->data = input;
    temp = temp->next;

}
}
```

If I do something like this, it works just fine doesn't matter what the size of link list is..

```
inline void myArray<T>::init() {
 Node<T>* temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL) {
    temp->data = 5;
    temp = temp->next;

}
}
```

So, Now I'm thinking the error has something to do with the input taking

Comment: 1. Format your code. 2. Give actual details about your problem. Not "some reason the head node gets lost". Explain what you are doing and why and what exactly went wrong. Imagine that someone was getting help from you and said this...

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I edited please take a look

Comment: What is `setSize`? What is `Node`? Is `myArray()` a constructor? You'd better describe your question in more detail

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you mean by "keep losing the head." But, you are re-assigning the head node to temp when you write "head=temp;". temp->next is assigned head in the previous line, however. So, you may wish to check your assignment statements to ensure that what you are doing is really what you want. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, wheather head is NULL or not, you should set `temp->next = head`.
Or, there is no link between the new Node and the existing nodes. It can not compromise a linked list.

```
inline myArray<T>::myArray(int size, T value) {
  setSize(size);
  for(int i = 0;i<size;i++) {
  Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>();

  if(i==size-1) {
    temp->data = 555555555;  //set a different value to distinguish between head and other node
    temp->next = 0;
  } else {
    temp->data = 0;
    temp->next = 0;
  }
  temp->next=head;
  head=temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried it but still having the same problem

Comment: Is `head` a member of `myArray<T>`?

Comment: Can you give an example of failed case?

Comment: It's a private member of Node<T>

Comment: It's a private member of Node<T>

Comment: yuan wen Now I get it what's the problem but I don't why this problem occuring. So, let me edit this question and this time I'll try to be super specific

Comment: Ok, but I suggest you paste all of your code here for us to reproduce it